# max-height property is ignored for flexbox with aspect-ration

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a page based on flexboxes which grows and shrinks proportionally. I want to limit it's maximum height to the screen height so that when it reaches the screen height, it doesn't grow but adds space to the left and right instead.

I tried to add `max-height: 100vh` and `margin: 0 auto` to the `body` but that doesn't help.

```html
<body class="center">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="menu center">menu</div>
    <div class="game">
      <div class="content">
        <div class="grid">
          <div class="cell center">1</div>
          <div class="cell center">2</div>
          <div class="cell center">3</div>
          <div class="cell center">4</div>
          <div class="cell center">5</div>
          <div class="cell center">6</div>
          <div class="cell center">7</div>
          <div class="cell center">8</div>
          <div class="cell center">9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="controls center">controls</div>
      </div>
      <div class="chat center">chat</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  max-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
}

.container {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
}

.menu {
  min-width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

.game {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  display: flex;
}

.content {
  flex: 3 0 200px;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  gap: 2px;
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
}

.cell {
  font-size: 2em;
  background-color: green;
}

.controls {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.chat {
  flex: 1 0 100px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.center {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Same code at codepen: https://codepen.io/Ihor0k/pen/wvmaaEO

Here is what it looks like on a narrow screen (which is nice):
[image]

And here is what it looks on a wide screen. It adds vertical scrollbar whereas I want to limit it's height to the screen height and add spaces to the left and right.
[image]

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour] first. Then 
read [how to ask questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). After 
that edit the question to meet the guidelines and provide 
a [repro] for debugging details. 
Please also read: [Can I just link to my website?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/) which also applies to any other external resource such as codepens.

Comment: Instead of setting aspect-ratio on the parent container, set it to the child elements. https://nimb.ws/0KozVi

Comment: @m4n0 tried your solution, it breaks an ability to become smaller when I make the screen narrower

Comment: Then try setting `max-width: 100vw` units for the same container? https://nimb.ws/pVS7Rx

Comment: You can also make use of media queries to make more adjustments like changing the number of columns so that it gives way for the whole container to become smaller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://codepen.io/cristianflorincalina/pen/MWVwaBE) is the solution

I've had to modify a bit the html structure (removed `center` from the body, removed the `content` div)

```html
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="menu center">
            menu
        </div>

        <div class="game">
            <div class="grid">
                <div class="cell center">1</div>
                <div class="cell center">2</div>
                <div class="cell center">3</div>
                <div class="cell center">4</div>
                <div class="cell center">5</div>
                <div class="cell center">6</div>
                <div class="cell center">7</div>
                <div class="cell center">8</div>
                <div class="cell center">9</div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="controls center">controls</div>
        </div>

        <div class="chat center">
            chat
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

As for the css, there were some modifications:

```css
body {
    margin: 0 auto;
    /* removed height, and flex from body */
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    width: 100%;
    /* not the best solution, but was the quickest */
}

.menu {
    min-width: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}

.game {
    max-width: calc(100vmin - 200px); /* minimum of viewport (height or width minus the minimum width for chat and menu */
    flex-grow: 1;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column; /* it's only the middle section with numbers and controls so it's column */
}

.grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    gap: 2px;
    aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
}

.cell {
    min-width: 10px; /* min width for each cell (you can put whatever you want here) */
    font-size: 2em;
    background-color: green;
}

.controls {
    height: 200px;
    background-color: yellow;
}

.chat {
    max-width: 30%; /* max width for chat, the rest should be taken by the game */
    flex-grow: 1;
    display: flex;
    background-color: lightblue;
}

.center {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I need to keep the spect ratio so that green cells remain squares then the first solution wouldn't work for me. Tried the second one and, the problem there is that all the content doesn't become smaller (by both width and height) when I make the screen narrower. E.g when screen width is ~600px it should look like on the first image in my original post. Whereas with your solution it just adds horizontal scrollbar.

Comment: Also `height: calc(100% - 200px);` probably wouldn't work because in real life `.controls` will not have fixed height

Comment: I changed the answer for the second solution. Let me know if it makes sense and if it works as expected :D

Comment: Great! Many Thanks. That's exactly what I needed! I've modified your solution a bit so that .game doesn't crop when the screen become too narrow. Also I put the game and the chat back into separate div as I have them as an individual Vue component in my project. Here is my solution, if you're interested: https://codepen.io/Ihor0k/pen/LYdVZpd